# POSIX threads vs Windows threads

Tags: windows, multithreading, pthreads, createthread

I have some experience with pthreads and am looking into threads in windows. They seem quite similar for the most part I am confused about one thing though. With pthreads the heap of the parent process is shared with the threads meaning that they all have access to the same memory. This does not seem to be the case with windows, or I am miss understanding something. With windows do you have to use a shared memory object to access the variables used by all?

Comment: No; the threads in the same process have access to the same memory space.

Comment: The only issue may be if two DLL's have different memory-manager instances.